# I have the min reqd. 10 reputation points so why am I not able to post image?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

As required by the community, I've 10 rep points which are needed to post an image. I need to post a function as an image and my research is stuck with every passing day of inactivity, I honestly think that by getting leads from the really wonderful people here I'll be able to do some good. So please help me...!

Comment: You can always put image on imgur (of something like this) and provide a link in the post; you can also flag it so some moderator could actually embed it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. i'll try doing that.

Comment: It may just take a while. Some features of the site only seem to update once per day. Has it been more than 24 hours & you still can't post images?

Comment: You don't need an image: $\TeX$ is better. I edited your question to insert the image in $\TeX$ format.

Comment: Thanks whuber. Sincerely appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: you should now have the power to add images, and your specific issue here has been resolved. Welcome to Cross Validated!